# how to reset the form fields to default values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two forms. form1's field data is sending to form2. form2 have 1 set 3 inline inputboxs and 1 reset button.when i clicked the reset button form1's go back to default state with out refresh the page.how can I do that?

**form1 **

```
<form id="formDrink" onclick="submit1(this.drinkname,this.drinkprice,this.drinkquantity)" >

      
<input type="text" id="drinkname" name="drinkname"  value="{{$drink->product_name}}">
 <input type="hidden"  id="drinkquantity" value="0" >
 <input type="text" id="drinkprice" name="drinkprice" value="{{$drink->selling_bottle}}">
</form>
```

**form2**

```
<form  class="form-inline"  id="kot">                                            
<input type="text" id="drinkName"   name="drinkname"  value="" readonly="">
<input type="text" id="drinkQuantity"   name="drinkquantity"  value="" readonly="">
<input type="text" id="drinkPrice"   name="drinkprice"  value="" readonly="">
<input type="button" id="resetForm"  onclick="drinkRemover()"  value="reset" />
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
 function drinkRemover(){
        $("#formDrink")[0].reset();
    }
```

I dont know why my javascript do not work.I tryed every posible ways but i cant reset the form1's fields to its default values.

Comment: Why not just set the button type to reset?.. `<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>`

Comment: I all already did it, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `reset` input type is for:

```html
<form class="form-inline" id="kot">
  <input type="text" id="drinkName" name="drinkname" value="drinkname">
  <input type="text" id="drinkQuantity" name="drinkquantity" value="drinkquantity">
  <input type="text" id="drinkPrice" name="drinkprice" value="drinkprice">
  <input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: the data is coming from form1. reseting form2 will not work. i want to reset form1

Comment: Then simply place a reset button in form1.